# Как реализовать условия в шорткоде в зависимости от страниц сайта на wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Есть сайт на wordpress на страницах которого через шорткод хочу выводить портфолио для каждой со своими особенностями.
В **functions.php** прописываю щорткод, указываю в условиях для какой страницы хочу, чтобы исполнялся `if( is_page(4814) ){..}`, но, к сожалению, на этом этапе еще *id страницы* не воспринимает и условие if не выполняется. Как реализовать?

```
function portfolio_list($atts, $content = null) {
..
        if( is_page(4814) ){
          $portfolios = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "qode_portfolios", true);
          if($portfolios[0]['optionUrl']) {
            $html .= qode_portfolios_function($portfolios[0]);
          }
        }
        else {
          $html .= "<a class='preview' href='". get_permalink() ."'><i class='icon-link icon-2x'></i>".__('Подробнее','qode')."</a>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден - в шорткод нужно поместить

global $post;

и до цикла **while** и/или `query_posts()` разместить условие `if( is_page(4814) ){..}`